# Large subspaces with small basic constants in finite-dimensional Banach spaces

Tags: banach-spaces

Let $B\in(1,\infty)$. I am interested in estimates for the
function $f_B(n)$ defined as the largest $k\in\mathbb{N}$
satisfying the condition:  Each $n$-dimensional Banach space
contains an $k$-dimensional subspace with basic constant at most
$B$.

Milman's improvement of the Dvoretzky theorem gives $f_B(n)\ge
c(B)\ln n$ for some $c(B)>0$. A straightforward Mazur-type
construction (I mean Theorem 1.a.5 in the 1st volume of
Lindenstrauss-Tzafriri) also gives a similar estimate. Any other
lower or upper estimates?

Comment: What is the definition of the *basic constant*? (sorry for my ignorance).

Comment: Have you checked what you can get from the technique in Mankiewicz, Piotr; Tomczak-Jaegermann, Nicole Embedding subspaces of ln∞ into spaces with Schauder basis. Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 117 (1993), no. 2, 459–465? From the statement you just get that $f_B(n)$ is not linear, but  I vaguely recall that they or somebody checked that $n^a$ was an upper bound for some specific $a<1$.

Comment: @Wlodzimierz For each Schauder basis in a Banach space the partial sums are bounded linear operators. The basic constant (or basis constant) is the supremum of the norms of these linear operators. See the mentioned book of Lindenstrauss-Tzafriri for more details.

Comment: @Bill No, I have not. Thank you for the reference, I definitely should check it. Although I did not mention it in the question, I am more interested in lower estimates (or in logarithmic upper estimates, which would kill the hope to improve the mentioned lower estimates).

Comment: I would like to add that the paper Szarek and Tomczak-Jaegermann (Adv. Math. 221 (2009), 331--342) provides a better lower estimate than the one mentioned above.